# Zend Framework 2 use my own Library and namespace confusion

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a library in ZF2 and really finding it tedious and difficult. My library will be used to perform tasks on images, no front end output. Having read as much as I can I have done the following process.

1. Created:

   ```
   vendor/mycompany/mylibrary/library/mylibrary/mylibrary.php
   ```
2. Contents of `mylibrary.php`:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace mylibrary;

   class mylibrary {

   }
   ```
3. Added:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "psr-0":  {"mylibrary\\":"vendor/mycompany/mylibrary/library/mylibrary/"}
   }
   ```

   to `composer.json`.
4. Ran composer:

   ```
   `sudo php composer.phar update`
   ```

   and had no errors and `autoload_namespaces.php` gets updated with the new namespace:

   ```
   return array(
       'mylibrary\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mycompany/mylibrary/library/mylibrary'),
       'Zend\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library'),
       'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
       'ZendPdf\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendpdf/library'),
   );
   ```
5. Added:

   `use mylibrary;`

   to `IndexController.php`

   and tried to instantiate the class:

   ```
   public function indexAction()
   {

       $mylibrary = new mylibrary();
       // .... etc etc
   ```

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mylibrary' not found in /the/root/to/my/site/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 22
```

Please could somebody have a look at what I have done and maybe tell me how I can instantiate my class without this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is your mylibrary class is in the mylibrary namespace and therefore your `use` statement should be changed to reflect that ...

```
use mylibrary\mylibrary;
```

The alternative is to omit the use statement and use the FQCN when instantiating your class

```
$mylibrary = new \mylibrary\mylibrary();
```

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use ZFTool to create a new module (this is how a library is called in ZF2), 
assuming you are using Git and you have Git bash installed, you can do the follow

- Clone the ZF2 skeleton, you'll get instruction here https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication
- Add the ZFTool dependency to the composer.json file

> ```
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.3.3",
>     "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
>     "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
> },
> ```

- Run php composer.phar update.
- To create a new module in your project, from the console, cd to the project root and run

> ./vendor/bin/zf.php create module MyModule

or type -v to see all available options

> ./vendor/bin/zf.php -v

Doing so your module will be created with the correct structure and automatically registered to the application. It will be created inside the application module dir.

- To make sure everything works you can create a simple route and controller, so open YourZFSkeleton/module/YourNewModule/config/module.config.php and add the follow

```
    namespace MyNewModule; 

    return array(
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),

        'controllers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller\Index' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller\IndexController',
            ),
        ),

        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => array(
                    'type' => 'Literal',
                    'priority' => 1000,
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/example',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

And the IndexController.php within the controller dir of your module

```
    namespace MyNewModule\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
        Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class IndexController 
        extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function indexAction() 
        {
            return new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

And the view script MyNewModule/view/my-new-module/index/index.phtml

> Hello world!

You can see it in action visiting

```
http://yourSiteUrlOrVhost/example
```

I didn't test this code, may contain errors or omissions :/

As already adviced, **never** edit anything inside the vendor dir, it contains dependencies that are automatically downloaded by composer.

If you like, you can create a new repo for your module and then add it ad dependency using composer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually creating files in `vendor`. If you want to be able to share your library with other applications, create the file(s) along with an appropriate `composer.json`. Put the library in its own source control repository, and then install it using composer into your main application.